# import CSV with missing data in pybrain sample

Tags: python, csv, import, pybrain

Can we use missing data in the sample for pybrain and can we import it from csv ?

The C0m4's code is nice but for a full sample (link below).

[How to load training data in PyBrain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139822/how-to-load-training-data-in-pybrain)

Is it possible for missing data sample ? And how to do that ? By what replace the missing values ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the missing values by others like e.g. means, or delete rows with missing data.

With mean you introduce bias and deleting you may reduce the sample...